# Touch-To-Focus on cameraOverlayView in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, focus, uiimagepickercontroller, setfocus, camera-overlay

I used to have touch to focus on my `cameraOverlayView` (in `UIImagePickerController`), but once I updated to iOS 5 it doesn't work.

I used a custom view class which I applied to my view in `cameraOverlayView`.
I made sure everything is connected and applied in Interface Builder.
I don't want to show camera controls. (`imagePicker.showsCameraControlls = NO`).

This is my code in the OverlayView class:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UIView * previewView = [[[[[[[[[[
                                     self.picker.view // UILayoutContainerView
                                     subviews] objectAtIndex:0] // UINavigationTransitionView
                                   subviews] objectAtIndex:0] // UIViewControllerWrapperView
                                 subviews] objectAtIndex:0] // UIView

           subviews] objectAtIndex:0] // PLCameraView
                             subviews] objectAtIndex:0]; // PLPreviewView
    [previewView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"Should Focus");
}
```

Do you guys have a different tap-to-focus method on an overlay?

Or do you know how to fix this?

THANK YOU SO MUCH IN ADVANCE!

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @hb922 Well I realized that instead of tap to focus, you can hold to focus in ios 5. It focuses, but it doesn't show the focus box or any other indicator. Therefore, in the app I was detecting whether the user was touching and holding the screen. If he did so for 0.67 seconds, I drew a custom focus box. I did all of this in a custom class of UIView which was also my cameraOverlayView.

Comment: If you absolutely need touch to focus, you might need to use AV Foundation to create a custom camera. There is no more touch to focus in UIImagePickerView unless you show the camera controls. Showing camera controls also allows the user to capture photos using the volume buttons. But I didn't want that in my app...

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that... but I'll try it and see how it goes...

Answer (score -1):

because ios5.0 
Touch events are not getting forwarded to the view in the cameraOverlayView property of UIImagePickerController.

please changed you init code like this:

```
// self.cameraOverlayView = [[UIView alloc] init];
// [self.cameraOverlayView addSubview:previewView];

[self.view addSubview:mask];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:previewView];
```

Comment: Where did you get mask and previewView from?  this is not a detailed answer.